# Adding row after row that has a specific value

Tags: r

Have a large data and Wish to be able to add a row after a row that has date of 01-31
An example:

```
id  place name  date    Measure 
1   24  aa  1989-01-29  0.6
1   24  aa  1989-01-30  0.47
1   24  aa  1989-01-31  0.25
1   24  bb  1989-01-29  0.18
1   24  bb  1989-01-30  0.37
1   24  bb  1989-01-31  0.81
1   25  aa  1989-01-29  0.92
1   25  aa  1989-01-30  0.43
1   25  aa  1989-01-31  0.8
2   24  aa  1989-01-29  0.75
2   24  aa  1989-01-30  0.15
2   24  aa  1989-01-31  0.61
```

I  am looking for an output like this and time of run is important (I have a big data)

```
id  place   name    date    Measure 
1   24  aa  1989-01-29  0.6
1   24  aa  1989-01-30  0.47
1   24  aa  1989-01-31  0.25
0   0   0        0      0
1   24  bb  1989-01-29  0.18
1   24  bb  1989-01-30  0.37
1   24  bb  1989-01-31  0.81
0   0   0        0      0
1   25  aa  1989-01-29  0.92
1   25  aa  1989-01-30  0.43
1   25  aa  1989-01-31  0.8
0   0   0        0      0
2   24  aa  1989-01-29  0.75
2   24  aa  1989-01-30  0.15
2   24  aa  1989-01-31  0.61
```

Any thought please

Comment: Is it always fixed width? i.e. x-x-31, x-x-31, x-x-31, ... ?

Answer (score 0):

Because your data frame has a few non-numeric columns ("date" and "name"), it probably makes more sense to create new rows with `NA` rather than `0`. Here's one way to do it:

```
# the data as provided
df <- read.table(text = 'id  place name  date    Measure 
1   24  aa  1989-01-29  0.6
1   24  aa  1989-01-30  0.47
1   24  aa  1989-01-31  0.25
1   24  bb  1989-01-29  0.18
1   24  bb  1989-01-30  0.37
1   24  bb  1989-01-31  0.81
1   25  aa  1989-01-29  0.92
1   25  aa  1989-01-30  0.43
1   25  aa  1989-01-31  0.8
2   24  aa  1989-01-29  0.75
2   24  aa  1989-01-30  0.15
2   24  aa  1989-01-31  0.61', header = T)

# indices of matching dates, then turned into a rolling sum
key.dates <- cumsum(grepl('01-31$', df$date))

# a blank data frame to store padded data
df.new <- data.frame(id = rep(NA, nrow(df) + max(key.dates)), place = NA, name = as.character(NA), date = as.Date(NA), Measure = NA, stringsAsFactors = F)

# copy the old data frame into the new, using the padded indices
df.new[1:nrow(df) + key.dates, ] <- df

   id place name       date Measure
1   1    24    1 1989-01-29    0.60
2   1    24    1 1989-01-30    0.47
3  NA    NA <NA>       <NA>      NA
4   1    24    1 1989-01-31    0.25
5   1    24    2 1989-01-29    0.18
6   1    24    2 1989-01-30    0.37
7  NA    NA <NA>       <NA>      NA
8   1    24    2 1989-01-31    0.81
9   1    25    1 1989-01-29    0.92
10  1    25    1 1989-01-30    0.43
11 NA    NA <NA>       <NA>      NA
12  1    25    1 1989-01-31    0.80
13  2    24    1 1989-01-29    0.75
14  2    24    1 1989-01-30    0.15
15 NA    NA <NA>       <NA>      NA
16  2    24    1 1989-01-31    0.61
```

Comment: @ jdobers thanks. I got this for the last line: "Error in as.Date.numeric(value) : 'origin' must be supplied"

Comment: @aorali Not sure why you're getting an error. I've updated my answer with the example data as I imported it.

Comment: I fixed the problem. But I need to place the new row after the 31st not after the 30th

Comment: So change `grepl('01-31$', df$date)` to `grepl('01-30$', df$date)`

Comment: Great, please mark as correct when you have a chance.